# Error in nltk package in Python2.7 Widnows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, nltk

I installed nltk using pip but when I import, it shows the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 35, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 333
    print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that NLTK requires Python 3.x. Notice this line, where the error is:

```py
print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
```

The `end=" "` is not valid Python 2.7, unless the Python file that uses `print` in that way contains the statement `from __future__ import print_function`.

In any case, you should really use Python 3.x anyway, now that Python 2.7 is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

[`nltk` 3.4](https://pypi.org/project/nltk/3.4.5/) supports Python 2.7. To install:

```
pip install "nltk<3.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

From  https://www.nltk.org/news.html

NLTK officially drops Python 2 support as of version 3.5. Last known version for Python 2 is:

```
pip install -U nltk==3.4.5
```

But you are strongly advised to use Python 3.